# При использовании wcscat возникает исключение "нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу"

Tags: c++

Приветствую! Есть такой фрагмент кода:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#define SIZEBUF 4
#define SIZEQUEST 30
#define RAD 10
int main()
{
    int nCountAtt = 0;
    wchar_t* pQuest = new wchar_t[SIZEQUEST];
    wchar_t* pBuff = new wchar_t[SIZEBUF];

    _itow(nCountAtt, pBuff, RAD);

    pQuest = L"Вы загадали число ";
    wcscat(pBuff, L"?");
    wcscat(pQuest, pBuff);   //здесь возникает ошибка

    delete[] pBuff;
    delete[] pQuest;
    return 0;
}
```

В отмеченной строке кода возникает описанное в заголовке исключение. Я понимаю, что происходит выход за пределы выделенной памяти, однако не могу понять, почему это происходит. Подскажите причину, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибок тут больше одной :)

```
wchar_t* pQuest = new wchar_t[SIZEQUEST];
pQuest = L"Вы загадали число ";
wcscat( pQuest, pBuff );
```

1. Выделяете память, её адрес присваиваете указателю `pQuest`
2. Тут же теряете это значение, перезаписывая указатель адресом из сегмента статических данных
3. Добавляете к этим данным что-то ещё, пытаясь влезть в readonly область.

Вероятно, имелось в виду что-то такое:

```
wchar_t* pQuest = new wchar_t[SIZEQUEST];
wstrcpy( pQuest, L"Вы загадали число " );
wcscat(pQuest, pBuff);
```

Но и тут будет ошибка: нет контроля длины записываемых в `pQuest` данных... А что с этим делать - уже самостоятельно :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, разжевали. Ушёл исправлять код. =)